# MongoDB/Mongoose Sort Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, database, nosql

```
Item.find().sort([['_id','descending']]).limit(15).each(function(doc) {
  client.send(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

Returns this error:

```
Error: Error: Illegal sort clause, must be of the form [['field1', '(ascending|descending)'], ['field2', '(ascending|descending)']]\n
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Item.find().sort('_id','descending').limit(15).each(function(err, doc) {
client.send(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try `.sort([['_id','desc']])`

Also you can try `.sort("_id")` but that defaults to ascending order.

Comment: stil get this error `{"stack":"Error: Error: Illegal sort clause, must be of the form [['field1', '(ascending|descending)'], ['field2', '(ascending|descending)']]\n    at [object Object].nextObject (/opt/local/lib/node/.npm/mongoose/1.1.24/package/support/node-mongodb-native/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:460:16)\n    at Array.0 (/opt/local/lib/node/.npm/mongoose/1.1.24/package/lib/mongoose/query.js:651:16)\n    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)","message":"Error: Illegal sort clause, must be of the form [['field1', '(ascending|descending)'], ['field2', '(ascending|descending)']]"}`

Comment: to add more context, my current solution not sorting works fine: `Item.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    for (var i = docs.length-2; i < docs.length; i++){
     client.send(JSON.stringify(docs[i]));
    } 
    
   });`

Comment: @float do you have the latest version of mongodb, express, mongoose, nodejs and mongodb-native-driver ?

Comment: mongodb@0.9.2 express@2.1.1 mongoose@1.1.24 node@v0.4.3

Comment: @Raynos does Mongoose need mongodb-native-driver to be installed separately? Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: @float express should install mongodb native-driver for you. Try updating express to 2.2, node to 0.4.6, mongoose to 1.2. I've personally had problems with the mongodb/mongoose API myself. So I switched to [Cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) which uses couchdb instead. Mongoose should also install mongodb native for you.

Comment: @float you may have an old version of mongodb native driver lying around. Try un installing mongodb native, express, install mongoose, install express.

Comment: @float then I'm stuck. Try couchdb or redis ;)

Comment: @Raynos thanks for the help, might just get rid of mongoose and use straight mongo

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Item.find().sort([['_id','1']]).limit(15).each(function(err, doc) {
  client.send(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```